# point traking on rotating Image - android

Tags: android, android-animation

In my application I have one Image which can be rotated... The rotation part is done.

now what I need to do is keep track of that rotation, if Part of the image is on certain angle there will be certain callback, So, the question is **How can i track only one point of image which keeps rotating?** Is there any workarroung? which can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You want to know the position of one of the pixels after your image is rotated around center by some degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you used the Matrix class from **android.graphics.Matrix** to rotate your image.

The matrix then holds all info you need and you can transform 2d points by the matrix like this:

```
float[] src = {x0,y0,x1,y1};
float[] dist = new float[4];
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.preRotate(90.0f);
matrix.mapPoints(dist,src);
```

this should rotate all points by 90 degrees for example.